# How to set a session from a GraphQL Resolver in NestJS?

Tags: express, session, authentication, graphql, nestjs

I have a GraphQL mutation that handling authentication for my NestJS app. It's set a login information inside an express-session. This method works fine in 'vanilla express'. But, when i do this in NestJS, the session is not changed. I wonder where did i go wrong?

I've tried using guard to set the express-session, but it doesnt work too.

```
 @Mutation('doLogin')
  async doLogin(@Parent() parent: any, @Args() args: any, @Context() context: any, @Info() info: any) {
    const login: Login = await authenticationService.doLogin(args.loginInput);
    context.session.session.login = login;
    console.log(context.session.session);
    return login;
  }
```

When i check the terminal, the session is changed just like i wanted

```
Session {
  cookie:
   { path: '/',
     _expires: 2019-07-15T04:48:50.599Z,
     originalMaxAge: 3600000,
     httpOnly: true,
     secure: true },
  login:
   Login {
     id: 1,
     username: 'admin',
     name: 'admin',
     email: 'admin@email.com',
     role: 'ADMIN',
     active: true
   }
```

But when it's leave the resolver, the login part is not there anymore

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [Authentication Docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication#graphql) specifically on GraphQL (at the bottom of the page) and how to add the req to the context of the incoming request so that you can make use of guards?

Comment: I already did that

i added the req to the GraphQL context. I can access it inside the resolver. But, when i try to modify it, the req.session didn't change when it goes out the resolver.